# Best way to migrate Visual C++ 6.0 to Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, migrate

I have a Visual C++ 6.0 solution and I need to migrate it to Visual Studio 2013. 
I've opened the solution with Visual Studio 2013 and it started "migrating" the solution for VS 2013 but when I want to build the solution I receive the following errors :

```
Error   4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPNLSVERSIONINFO'
```

All these errors are from MFC files (atlwinverapi.h, atlcore.h, afxstat_.h etc ).

Example:

In atlwinverapi.h at line 85 :

```
int __cdecl _AtlLCMapStringEx(_In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpLocaleName, _In_ DWORD dwMapFlags,
                              _In_ LPCWSTR lpSrcStr, _In_ int cchSrc,
                              _Out_opt_ LPWSTR lpDestStr, _In_ int cchDest,
                              _In_opt_ LPNLSVERSIONINFO lpVersionInformation,
                              _In_opt_ LPVOID lpReserved, _In_opt_ LPARAM sortHandle);
```

And the error is:

```
Error   4   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPNLSVERSIONINFO'
```

I'm doing something wrong or there are any steps to follow before building the solution ?

Comment: Considering the massive differences between those two versions, both in VS itself and the platforms they target, 4 errors seems small. Have you considered trying to fix the errors? Also why upgrade to an old version of VS when 2015 has been out for a long time?

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to specify the number of errors. There are 1000 errors like the one described by me. All the errors are the same ( identifier not found ).

Comment: Migrating should be straight forward. Did you redefine `LPNLSVERSIONINFO` somewhere in your source files ?

Comment: No, there is no redefine of LPNLSVERSIONINFO  in my source files.

Comment: Hard to tell what this could be whithout more information. Edit your question and put some examples of the errors and show the corresponding parts of the source code where the errors occur.

Comment: Done! I've added one example where this error occurs. I think there is something wrong with the project settings.

Comment: Something is not adding up. The minimum Windows version for type you're describing, a pointer to a `NLSVERSIONINFO` struct, is Vista. VS 6.0 is 5 years older. Also, it's deprecated now. It could probably be "fixed" with a `#define LPNLSVERSIONINFO *NLSVERSIONINFOEX`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @madalin.mamuleanu Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190000/build-issues-after-upgrading-app-from-vs2005-to-vs2012

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the link. I've tried the solutions from there but I've still got the same errors.

Comment: @Adam: The minimum **supported** version is Vista. Microsoft has been removing references to XP from MSDN.

Comment: @MSalters The original project was created on Windows XP, and I need to migrate the project to Visual Studio 2013. I've tried to add #include <SDKDDKVer.h> in stdafx but I have the same errors.

Comment: @madalin.mamuleanu: That won't magically fix your errors. What minimum version of Windows are you targetting, and how?

Comment: `#define WINVER 0x0601
    #define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 0x0601`  <br/> All these are defined in `stdafx.h`

Comment: In property pages -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General I've had the following text in Additional Include Directories: `..\Shared;.\;..\..\..\sdk\psdk\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` . I've deleted that line and now I have fewer errors. I do have those sdk files ( there are from DirectShow )